# How to add the new Event Logger to a DNN Scheduler Class in DNN 9.10.2?

Tags: event-handling, dotnetnuke, dnn9

How can I add a constructor with a reference to _eventLogger = DependencyProvider.GetRequiredService(); in a DNN Scheduler class?

The Dependency Provider can be inherited through the PortalModuleBase class, which I can do on my current Web Form module. The issue is that it is Protected and I can't inherit it again on the same View.ascx page in a Scheduler Class.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same problem as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72046950/dnn-resolve-iportalinfo-service/73149800#73149800). Dependency injection in DNN is not (yet) available in Scheduler classes, only in webforms code-behind.

Comment: It seems to work in 9.11 - just tried it with the EventLogger in my BusinessController class, that seems to work, at least there was no compiler error or deprecated warning anymore. See [The dreaded "Deprecated" and "Obsolete"](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/discussions/4091)