# DNN: Resolve IPortalInfo service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dotnetnuke, dnn9

I'm trying to use dependency injection in DNN to resolve the IPortalInfo service in my SchedulerClient and in my FeatureController. I want to access the current PortalId somehow. But for the SchedulerClient I receive the following error when trying to use the constructor dependency injection:

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'DotNetNuke.Abstractions.Portals.IPortalInfo' while attempting to activate 'XXX'.
```

For the FeatureController class it is not working either since it requires a parameterless constructor. Is there any other way to resolve the IPortalInfo service. Currently I'm using the `DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalInfo` class but it is deprecated.

`(IPortalInfo)DependencyProvider.GetService(typeof (IPortalInfo));` using the PortalModuleBase is not working for the IPortalInfo.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no way to use dependency injection in DNN in other classes than webforms code-behind at the moment.